# How to define docker image name from within docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-compose

I've got a directory called `thing` with my docker compose project:

```
thing
├── Dockerfile
└── docker-compose.yml
```

The contents of docker-compose.yml:

```
master:
  build: .
```

Whenver I run `docker-compose build` in this folder, this will produce a docker image called `thing_master`. I'd like to specify in docker-compose.yml another name for my image. Is this possible?

– I know I can run `docker-compose -p [image_name] build` or set the environment variable `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`, but that's not what I wish to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now possible in Compose 1.6 ([rc2 is out now](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.6.0-rc2)).

Using 1.6, you can have both `build` and `image` on the same service:

```
version: "2"

services:
  master:
    build: .
    image: my_image_name:my_tag
```

Build will use the image name to tag the image.

Comment: Actually, I'm now running `docker-compose version 1.6.0rc2, build 695c692` and I cannot define the image name like that; `ERROR: Validation failed, reason(s):
Service 'master' has both an image and build path specified. A service can either be built to image or use an existing image, not both.`

Comment: Your syntax is slightly off. You need to specify `version: 2` and put `master` inside of `services`. I'll create a correct answer.

Comment: This wasn't meant to be a full config, just showing the relevant section. I can flush out the rest.

Comment: Note that in rc2 version is an int, but in the official release it will be a string, so I've quoted the version to reflect that.